# How to use apache rewrite to rewrite all traffic from /admin/recurring/foobar/123 to /admin/recurring/public/foobar/123

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I just installed laravel into /admin/recurring
but then I found out that all the goods are in public/
How do I point all traffic coming into /admin/recurring/foo/bar/123
to actually call the request to /admin/recurring/public/foo/bar/123

Here is what I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But this does not work. It gives me a Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. in Laravel 5.3

Comment: You don't need to make any changes to htaccess file. Index.php under public is already designed to handle the requests. All you need to do is to point your domain to public folder (etc... /admin/recurring/public). Then you can define all your routes as explained here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing

Comment: I can't do that, I have an entire website surrounding it

Comment: check this post if helps http://laravel.io/forum/11-25-2014-installing-laravel-in-a-subdirectory

Comment: @H.Kontodios I checked it out but i'm not seeing a definitive answer to this. Although it was informative.

Comment: FallbackResource /admin/recurring/public/index.php kind-of works, like it gets to laravel, but the problem is laravel is showing a NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite is not needed for this. You should, instead:

```
<Directory /path/to/admin/recurring>
  FallbackResource /admin/recurring/public/index.php
</Directory>
```

(Note: This assumes you're running at least 2.2.16 or later. Which you should be. 2.4 has been out for close to 5 years now.)

Also, if this is in a .htaccess file, you just need the `FallbackResource` line, in `/path/to/admin/recurring/.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this and check if it works?
In directory tag add full path to `/admin/recurring` .

```
<Directory "/admin/recurring">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Well i'm using a .htaccess file inside of admin/recurring/.htaccess, and i copied   RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
but nothing happened